# Encrypting passwords with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, encryption

**Problem:** 
Write a program called crypto.js that encrypts passwords containing uppercase/lowercase characters, digits, and special characters. Use Pizza2Day! For the password.
See Sample Execution Below:

This program will encrypt user passwords.

Password: Pizza2Day!

Encrypting ……………

Encrypted Password: Njaam2Fmc!

**My code:**

```
function crypto() {
  var pass = "Pizza2Day!";
  var flag = 0;
  var encryptPass = "";
  var originalValues = [
    "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
  ];
  var encryptedValues = [
    "m", "h","t","f","g","k","b","p","j","w","e","r","q","s","l","n","i","u","o","x","z","y","v","d","c","a"
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
    flag = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < originalValues.length; j++) {
      if (originalValues[j] == pass.charAt(i)) {
        encryptPass = encryptPass + encryptedValues[j];
        flag = 1;
        break;
      } else if (originalValues[j].toUpperCase() == pass.charAt(i)) {
        encryptPass = encryptPass + encryptedValues[j].toUpperCase();
        flag = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (flag == 0) {
      encryptPass = encryptPass + pass.charAt(i);
    }
  }
}
console.log("New Password: " + encryptPass);
```

**The issues that I am having:** The file does not print anything
I just want to have an idea of what I am doing wrong. And how can I fix this issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: Look in the developer console for hints of possible errors. Also - it looks like you're doing the `console.log()` outside of your function.

Comment: You never call your function.  And you're trying to `console.log()` a value that doesn't exist in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the function!
You should have the console.log call the crypto function.

```
console.log("New Password: " + crypto());
```

https://jsbin.com/yonowaqesa/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

Well there are a few things that can be improved:

1. You are trying to log the local variable `encryptPass` outside the `crypto()` function
2. In the `console.log()` expression, call the function
3. The function should return the `encryptPass` variable

Hope this helped